# Pixar USD LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, python-3.x, visual-studio, compiler-errors, nvidia

I'm working on a C++ program that creates a .usda file using the Python 3 pre-built libraries from Nvidia (https://developer.nvidia.com/usd). There are a lot of external libraries, and I can't pin down which one is causing a bunch of compiler issues. There are a handful of header files (stage.h, mesh.h to be specific) that will prevent my program from compiling. Other header files I've used from the package don't cause these errors.

I gather from research that I'm potentially missing an include/lib directory or something was compiled on a different version, but how can I find which file(s) are missing or compiled improperly?

I'm using Windows 10, Visual Studio 2017, Python 3.6, and Boost 1.68. Nvidia libraries are in C:\USDP3

Includes:  C:\USDP3\include  C:\Program Files\boost_1_68_0

Libraries:   C:\USDP3\lib  C:\Program Files\boost_1_68_0  C:\USDP3\libs

Example code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#define NOMINMAX
#define TBB_USE_ASSERT 0
#define TBB_USE_THREADING_TOOLS 0
#include "pxr/pxr.h"
#include "pxr/usd/usd/stage.h"
#include <iostream>

PXR_NAMESPACE_USING_DIRECTIVE

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //Create Stage
    UsdStage::CreateNew("Test.usda");
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

Causes these errors:

```
1>test1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) private: static char * * pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__::Sdf_Pool<struct pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__::Sdf_PathPropTag,24,8,16384>::_regionStarts" (__imp_?_regionStarts@?$Sdf_Pool@USdf_PathPropTag@pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__@@$0BI@$07$0EAAA@@pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__@@0PAPEADA)
1>test1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) private: __cdecl pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__::Sdf_PrimPathNode::~Sdf_PrimPathNode(void)" (__imp_??1Sdf_PrimPathNode@pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__@@AEAA@XZ)
1>test1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) private: __cdecl pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__::Sdf_MapperArgPathNode::~Sdf_MapperArgPathNode(void)" (__imp_??1Sdf_MapperArgPathNode@pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__@@AEAA@XZ)
1>test1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) private: __cdecl pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__::Sdf_ExpressionPathNode::~Sdf_ExpressionPathNode(void)" (__imp_??1Sdf_ExpressionPathNode@pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__@@AEAA@XZ)
1>test1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void __cdecl pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__::Sdf_PrimPartPathNode::operator delete(void *)" (__imp_??3Sdf_PrimPartPathNode@pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__@@SAXPEAX@Z)
1>test1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) private: __cdecl pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__::Sdf_PrimPropertyPathNode::~Sdf_PrimPropertyPathNode(void)" (__imp_??1Sdf_PrimPropertyPathNode@pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__@@AEAA@XZ)
1>test1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) private: __cdecl pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__::Sdf_TargetPathNode::~Sdf_TargetPathNode(void)" (__imp_??1Sdf_TargetPathNode@pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__@@AEAA@XZ)
1>test1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void __cdecl pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__::Sdf_PropPartPathNode::operator delete(void *)" (__imp_??3Sdf_PropPartPathNode@pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__@@SAXPEAX@Z)
1>test1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static bool __cdecl pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__::Tf_RefPtr_UniqueChangedCounter::_RemoveRef(class pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__::TfRefBase const *)" (__imp_?_RemoveRef@Tf_RefPtr_UniqueChangedCounter@pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__@@SA_NPEBVTfRefBase@2@@Z)
1>test1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) private: __cdecl pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__::Sdf_RelationalAttributePathNode::~Sdf_RelationalAttributePathNode(void)" (__imp_??1Sdf_RelationalAttributePathNode@pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__@@AEAA@XZ)
1>test1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) private: __cdecl pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__::Sdf_MapperPathNode::~Sdf_MapperPathNode(void)" (__imp_??1Sdf_MapperPathNode@pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__@@AEAA@XZ)
1>test1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: void __cdecl pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__::Sdf_PathNode::_RemovePathTokenFromTable(void)const " (__imp_?_RemovePathTokenFromTable@Sdf_PathNode@pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__@@IEBAXXZ)
1>test1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__::TfRefPtr<class pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__::UsdStage> __cdecl pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__::UsdStage::CreateNew(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,enum pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__::UsdStage::InitialLoadSet)" (__imp_?CreateNew@UsdStage@pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__@@SA?AV?$TfRefPtr@VUsdStage@pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__@@@2@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@W4InitialLoadSet@12@@Z)
1>test1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) private: __cdecl pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__::Sdf_PrimVariantSelectionNode::~Sdf_PrimVariantSelectionNode(void)" (__imp_??1Sdf_PrimVariantSelectionNode@pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__@@AEAA@XZ)
1>test1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) private: static char * * pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__::Sdf_Pool<struct pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__::Sdf_PathPrimTag,24,8,16384>::_regionStarts" (__imp_?_regionStarts@?$Sdf_Pool@USdf_PathPrimTag@pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__@@$0BI@$07$0EAAA@@pxrInternal_v0_19__pxrReserved__@@0PAPEADA)'
```

Comment: You are missing a link to an import library for a dll.

Comment: That makes sense, but I can't figure out _which_ dll is missing. Every library I can find in the package is in in a path that I've included. Is there anything in the error message here that actually helps me find the missing file?

Comment: How many .dll files are there with this project? It's not a missing `dll` its that you are not linking to a .lib (import library not static library) file that goes with an existing dll file from this project.

Comment: Stage.h has a lot of headers in it, so I'm not sure exactly how many dll files there are. Here's what stage.h looks like: https://github.com/PixarAnimationStudios/USD/blob/master/pxr/usd/lib/usd/stage.h

Comment: @mnewby1 did you manage to solve this? I am stuck with the same.

Comment: same issue, unresolved still :(

Answer (score 2):

You should have following things in your compilation step setup properly:
Preprocessor flags:

```
TBB_USE_DEBUG=0
YY_NO_UNISTD_H
BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK
BOOST_PYTHON_NO_PY_SIGNATURES
BUILD_OPTLEVEL_DEV
NDEBUG
NOMINMAX
_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE
NO_WARN_MBCS_MFC_DEPRECATION
```

Include Directories: `<usd_install>\include;<usd_install>\include\boost-1_70;<Python374>\include`

Libraries to link against: `usd_ms.lib`(when USD is compiled as monolithic shared lib)

Else, basic ones: `arch.lib;pxOsd.lib;sdf.lib;usd.lib;vt.lib;tf.lib;`

Render: `hd.lib;hdx.lib;`

More: `gf.lib;cameraUtil.lib;trace.lib;hf.lib;`(depending on which ones you are using.)
Their counterpart dlls should discoverable or best should be in same dir. as your executable.

Check USD's cmake files to get better idea on what to include.